# Is more than 1 idle connection necessary to have in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, go

**The scenario:**

I'm testing out a project written by another engineer in Go to interface with a mysql database. It came to my attention that in Go, whenever a new mysql connection is created, the defaults for this connection are set such that connections never expire.

We recently had a bug in our code that resulted in the proposed statement queue in mysql being completely filled up, resulting in all database requests being denied.
The proposed solution for this bug is to clear out all mysql connections every 24 hours to prevent the proposed statement queue from being filled up.

It is my understanding that our code spawns new connections automatically as needed, and hence clearing out all connections every 24 hours should have no unintended consequences.

The underlying reason why this queue is being filled up seems to be a disconnect between GO language cancelling a connection or request; whereas in mysql, the connection still exists but is only idle.  So the proposed solution is to clear out these idle requests and allow them to timeout, using the following code:

```
conn.SetConnMaxLifetime(24 * time.Hour) 
conn.SetConnMaxIdleTime(1 * time.Hour)  
conn.SetMaxOpenConns(30)                
conn.SetMaxIdleConns(1)
```

**What I seek to understand:**

What advantage is there for keeping idle connections, and could there be a situation where more than 1 idle connection is needed?

Are there any unintended consequences that haven't been considered; that could result in a future issue where all database requests get denied?

Comment: Why is it an issue to keep connections open? I'm assuming there's an upper limit, and there shouldn't be a major cost to just having those connections on stand-by.

Comment: "Is there ever a scenario where more than 1 idle connection would be necessary?" -- Depends on how you define "necessary".  The reason to want more than 0 idle connections is to be prepared for new requests that come in. It's exactly the same way you might want idle cashiers at a supermarket.

Comment: It's for performance tuning. More idle conns means new requests go faster, they can grab an idle conn rather than waiting on a new conn. It also uses more connections on the database end, which could end up harming performance if you have many client hosts with many open connections. You'll have to balance it out in your particular situation.

Comment: It's an issue to keep the connections open because we hit the upper limit of ~16,000 connections and hence no new ones could be formed.

Comment: Flimsy, is there any drawback to simply creating a new connection whenever one is needed; rather than keeping an idle one open?

Comment: Ah brilliant explanation Adrian, thank you so much! That makes perfect sense that creating a new connection each time would be a lot slower.

Comment: From [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns) "The default max idle connections is currently 2. This may change in a future release". So changing from 2 to 1 is unlikely to have the impact you hope. My guess would be that you are failing to close something (i.e. not [closing `rows`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Close)) and that is why you are seeing additional connections created (if that is the case setting `SetMaxOpenConns(30)` will make this obvious, your code will lock waiting for a free connection).